# Spark SQLContext does not work on CDH5.3

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera-cdh, apache-spark-sql

I am running spark 1.2 on CDH 5.3 and trying a simple code in spark-shell
I am failing on 
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
with the error:
not found : type SQLContext

What is wrong with my environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you import it:

`import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext`

Comment: How come it is not in the default path/import?

Comment: Not everyone needs it.